# Docker Continuous Integration using TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, docker

Is there a way that I could do CI using TeamCity and Docker? What I have so far is a Dockerfile that would install TeamCity and configure build agent on a base ubuntu image.

What I want is to have TeamCity call a DockerFile on every commit to SVN or GIT. This DockerFile would actually fetch the latest sources from SVN or GIT and run my integration Tests.

Additionally, how could I manage integration tests against trunk and branch? For example, I have a branch 1.0 and trunk. When I release a branch, I want to run the branch against all the integration tests. Now the integration tests might contain additional tests that actually require a trunk version. How do I handle this? Is there a way using Docker to acheive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention what build tool you're using, but there are plugins for [Gradle](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin) and [maven](https://github.com/rhuss/docker-maven-plugin) that let you build images, start containers, and so on. They'll at least give you the tools to build what you want.